# Is it possible to retrieve photo by its name using predicate in Obj-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, phasset

I wonder if it is possible to retrieve a photo from photo album using predicate in Obj-C with `PHAsset` Library?

I ask this question because I don't want to browse the entire album to retrieve only one photo.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean with "name"? You can filter photos/videos by the local identifier and other properties like width, height, mediaType. But there is no name or title property for a PHAsset.

Comment: Name means the filename for exemple : "IMG_XXX.JPG".

Comment: On iOS 8 there is no filename property. On iOS 9 you can use originalFilename property of PHAssetResource, but you can filter for it.

Comment: But when i'm using ALAssetRepresentation i'm able to get the file name. What's the difference?

Comment: ALAssetsFramework is deprecated and only allows you to access assets that are physically stored on the device. If the user has iCloud Photo Library enabled, you will run into issues using ALAssetsFramework. Then you need to use Photos-Framework/PHAsset and on iOS 8 there is no way to directly query the filename of a PHAsset.

Comment: Ok i understand, thank you for the reply, i mark the subject resolved .

Comment: PHAssetResource